# Spyder's Warning: "Session/line number not unique in database"

Tags: python, spyder

When I am programming in Spyder it happens from time to time that I get an error message like this:

```
ERROR! Session/line number was not unique in database. History logging moved to new session
```

I never really bothered with it, because I couldn't see any effect it had on the outcome of my code. However, just to be sure, I'd like to know what exactly it means, for which reasons this error tends to occur and whether/how I should fix it. Google wasn't a great help for that matter, but from naive observation, I have the hunch that it is related to printing things to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) It seems this error occurs when IPython fails to write cached entries to its history database. You can find it in [this file](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/history.py).

Comment: Has the part of Spyder managing the console line numbers changed since March 2016? I have a similar issue with Jupyter Notebook, but I am unable to reproduce it with Spyder v. 3.1.4.

Comment: Spyder doesn't handle this but IPython, as it can be seen in the file I referenced above.

Comment: So it is not Spyder which passes the line number (directly or not) to [store_inputs()](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/history.py#L691)?