# Dependency between "Session/line number was not unique in database." error and Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook

For some time I am getting the following error (warning?):

> ERROR! Session/line number was not unique in database. History logging moved to new session

when working with Jupyter notebook (`<XXXX>` is a number, e.g. 9149).
As the same error has been reported for Spyder ([Spyder's Warning: "Session/line number not unique in database"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35986087/spyders-warning-session-line-number-not-unique-in-database)) my guess is that there is some problem with the IPython kernel logging.

The question is: may there be any relation between running my code and the error?

**Is it likely the error is caused by my code?** I touch IPython API as following:

```
import IPython 

def beep():
    Python.display.display(IPython.display.Audio(url="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg", autoplay=True))

def play_sound(self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset=None):
    self.showtraceback((etype, value, tb), tb_offset=tb_offset)
    beep()

get_ipython().set_custom_exc((Exception,), play_sound)
```

I use the `beep()` function in my code. I also work with large data which results in `MemoryError` exceptions.

And more importantly, **may the error affect my code behaviour** (given I do not try to access the logs)?

[EDIT]
It seems the issue is different than [Spyder's Warning: "Session/line number not unique in database"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35986087/spyders-warning-session-line-number-not-unique-in-database) as I am able to reproduce it with Jupyter Notebook but not with Spyder.

Comment: What exactly are you doing here? And I see some syntax issue around the beep function?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Defining a function and a hook to play a sound of horse neighing after my calculations are either completed or an unhandled exception is raised.
I am 100% sure there is no SyntaxError.

Comment: Yes, my bad didn't scroll horizontally. Two things. What happens when you removing logging? Also if you move `IPython.display.Audio(url="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg", autoplay=True)` inside the function and keep default value as None. Check if None then initiate the sound

Comment: @TarunLalwani I have removed playing with the `logging` module and have rewritten the `beep()` function - the warning is still present.

Comment: This sounds like your IPython history database got corrupted. Try cleaning it up (i.e. remove/temporary relocate your `$IPYTHONDIR/profile_default/history.sqlite` file) and see if it still happens.

Comment: @zwer I have no `$IPYTHONDIR` set - will `$HOME/.ipython` work instead? I guess I need to restart the Jupyter Notebook for that to work?

Comment: @abukaj - yep, `$HOME/.ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite` in that case. And yes, you need to restart the Notebook to see the difference. You can move/rename the file temporarily to check if it indeed is a data corruption issue so you don't clear your history for nothing if something else is the issue.

Comment: @zwer so far I have restarted the kernel (not the notebook) and browsed both the old and the new database. It does not seem to be database corruption, but there indeed was a primary key conflict. Please see the partial answer I have posted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is only a partial answer - the bounty is still eligible.

The error does depend on my code - at least when there is `SyntaxError`.

I have reproduced it with three following cells.

```
In [31]: print(1)
         1

In [31]: print 2
           File "<ipython-input-32-9d8034018fb9>", line 1
             print 2
                   ^
         SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

In [32]: print(2)
         2
         ERROR! Session/line number was not unique in database. History logging moved to new session 7
```

As you can see the line counter has been not increased in the second cell (with syntax issues).

Inspired by @zwer's comment, I have queried the `$HOME/.ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite` database:

```
sqlite> select session, line, source from history where line > 30;
6|31|print(1)
6|32|print 2
7|32|print(2)
```

It is clear that the line counter for the second cell has been increased in the database, but not in the notebook.

Thus when the third cell has been executed successfully, the notebook attempted to store its source with the same line, which offended the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint:

```
sqlite> .schema history
CREATE TABLE history
                (session integer, line integer, source text, source_raw text,
                PRIMARY KEY (session, line));
```

As a result, [a failsafe](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/ba28f802ceaa35888339cf1d3bdaed614364a6a1/IPython/core/history.py#L781) has been triggered which issued the warning and created a new session.

I guess the issue is not affecting my code behaviour, however I miss a credible source for such statement.

Comment: It happened the same for me. The reason of my problem was that my script was encrypted in a strange format. I just had to change it to UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same error when I was trying to run some asyncio code in a jupyter notebook. The gist was like this (might make sense to those familiar with asyncio)

```
cell #1 
output = loop.run_until_complete(future)

cell #2
print(output)
```

Run both cells together, and I would get OP's error.
Merge the cells together like so, and it ran cleanly

```
cell #1 
output = loop.run_until_complete(future)
print(output)
```

Answer (score -1):

This problem arises in the *Jupyter Notebook* cells when the cells have the same line number.
What you can do - if you are in *Jupyter Notebook* - is just restart the kernel.
The error will be solved.

Comment: The problem is that after restart the state is lost. And the state may be worth several days of computation.

Comment: @abukaj Dude! Don't store several days of computation in RAM. Serialize it somehow! Pickle/json/csv/anything..